# How to dynamically render a list of different datatables

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, datatables, vuetify.js

Support the functionality for a user to create/remove dynamic datatables which will be persisted in the backend.

```
// statically typed data table
    <v-data-table
        :pagination.sync="pagination"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        class="elevation-1"
      >
        <template v-slot:items="props">
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.column1 }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.column2 }}</td> 
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.column3 }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.column4 }}</td>
          </td>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
```

However my case is:

```
<template v-for="table in tables">
    //where table will be a new <v-data-table> component with arbitrary rows 
</template>
```

In addition those datatables will have real-time updates thus I have to somehow link each datatable state with vuex to enhance reactivity.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to fist step for you, just combine `v-for` and `v-data-table`.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QRXyBg?editors=1010

And iterate over `tables` property. You can share `headers`.
If you need dynamic/reactive data, just update `tables` property from `methods` or some other places.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However the first part is the easy thing (iterate the tables), the second part is where I really need a good feedback. How can I populate data into each datatable derive from a persisted source, which in my case is vuex? I other words how to bind each table with dynamic real time data?

Comment: You should show some code. Example or code that doesn't work.

Comment: Btw. check Vuex getters, can be useful for you.